# When I try to usee public_key.encrypt(), it's doesn't work (Python Cryptography module)

Tags: python-3.x, python-cryptography

When I try to use `public_key.encrypt()` with the Cryptography module (Python 3.7.9), it doesn't work, here is the error:

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'unsigned char *' must be a bytes or list or tuple, not str
```

Here is my code:

**Main.py**

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding

with open("private.key", "rb") as f:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(f.read(), password=None)

public_key = private_key.public_key()

message = "Hello, World"
encrypted_message = public_key.encrypt(
    message,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)
```

**private.key**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the [documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicKey.encrypt) `encrypt` takes a message as `bytes` and not `str`.